# NetBeans - Expanding JDK file list

Tags: netbeans, ide

Is it possible to stop expanding list of JDK files in Libraries folder after clicking on class name and going to declatation inside JDK?

Screen (after clicking on STRING class):

[image]

Whole list is expanding...

[image]

Comment: You probably have "View -> Synchronize editor with views" enabled.

Comment: That's right! Thanks a lot! Now I can be much more "productive" :)